# Executing one Asyntask after completion of the previous

Tags: android, facebook

I need to be able to execute one asyntask after the completion of another. I am trying to do it by firing the 2nd asyntask in the `onPostExecute()` method of the first one.

But the 2nd asyntask is not getting fired. If however I call it manually from elsewhere it fires but since it attempts to post values retrived after the 1st asyntask is executed, it tries to send null values.

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
    //Asynctask to get Getting fb profile details
        private class FetchOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            String fb_token;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Get user defined values
                fb_token = token;


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String response = "";
                String Urls = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Urls +token);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                try {
                    httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("Response", "Hi From e1 : " + e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.v("Response", "Hi From 2 : "+response.toString());
                    return response;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("Response", "Hi From e2 : " + e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
                super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
                Log.v("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        String email = jsonObj.getString("email");
                        String firstName = jsonObj.getString("first_name");
                        String lastName = jsonObj.getString("last_name");
                        String gender = jsonObj.getString("gender");
                        String country = jsonObj.getString("locale");
                        id = jsonObj.getString("id");
                        user = firstName.concat(" ");
                        user = user.concat(lastName);
                        image = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
 Log.v("Fb name", "Testing Name : " + user);
                        new UploadOperation().execute();

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what gets printed in the logcat when this Asyntask gets executed

```
06-29 13:06:14.707    6396-6396/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample V/tag﹕ Token:
    CA******************************************************************************************************G
06-29 13:06:15.427    6396-6438/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample V/Response﹕ Hi From 2 : {"id":"910************","first_name":"S********","gender":"male","last_name":"Verma","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/910*********\/","locale":"en_GB","name":"S******* Verma","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2015-06-22T04:17:39+0000","verified":true}
```

I did some digging around and found out that the `onPostExecute()` method is never fired so the rest of the code is never executed. But I can't understand why it wont get fired!!!

And this is the code of the 2nd Asyntask that this one tries to fire

```
 //Asynctask to save fb details
    private class UploadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String api_key, user_name, img_path;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Get user defined values
                api_key = id;
                user_name = user;
                img_path = image;

         //Initiate ProgressBar
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Logging you in ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response = "";
            String Urls = "http://192.168.100.51/task_manager/v1/";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Urls +"facebookid");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_name",  user_name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id",  api_key));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_img_path",  image));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("Response", "Hi From e1 : " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.v("Response", "Hi From 2 : "+response.toString());
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("Response", "Hi From e2 : " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");
                    error(error, message, api_key);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are not getting the response from the Url, or there could be a error in the network, Have you checked whether you are getting the response or not.?

Comment: @Kartheek I am getting the response from the url wait let me update the question

Comment: @hoomi which Asyntask are you talking about? `FetchOperation` one? And I dont have any exception in my logcat also can't understand why I would need a `error` and `message` values in the first one. Could you please explain with codes

Comment: sorry my bad read the wrong code

Comment: `String email = jsonObj.getString("email");` I do not see 'email' in your json

Comment: @hoomi it's cool, I found out what the issue is happening but can't understand why it is happening. The `jsonStr` for the first Asyntask is null even though I am getting values from facebook.

Comment: @hoomi that's right, I forgot to delete email from there but the issue is that part of the code is never executed!!! I don't understand why `jsonStr` is null, even when `resonse.toString()` prints all the data which I can see in the logcat

Comment: What is the output og this line?  `Log.v("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);`

Comment: @hoomi just discovered that `onPostExecute()` is not run at all. That line `Log.v("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);` is not there in my logcat. From which I can conclude that for some reason the `onPostExecute()` isn't firing

Comment: Are you sure? Can you remove "\n" from the "Result:\n" and check again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81842/discussion-between-rick-roy-and-hoomi).

Answer (score 1):

A perfect solution for you would be to use http://jdeferred.org/

You can chain multiple calls, have different callbacks (depending if it's successful, failed or something that always has to run), and just have more control over your calls.